# Html Agility Pack Load method issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am using the Html Agility pack. When the Load method of HtmlDocument class is passed the URL like "http://www.stackoverflow.com" it says the URI is not in correct format.

```
    doc.Load(TextBoxUrl.Text, Encoding.UTF8 );
```

the url I try is this http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAP can not load from url, only from file or from a string. Use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the page.

For example:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    doc.LoadHtml(wc.DownloadString(TextBoxUrl.Text));
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. Successful. Now I am trying to read elements like if (doc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//Link[@rel='shortcut icon or @rel='apple-touch-icon'");
            if (node != null)
            { 
            HtmlAgilityPack .HtmlAttribute attr= node.Attributes ["href"];

            }
        }    but is not working

Comment: @user1575229 instead of asking questions in comments, please create a new question with more description and some sample/url